# $C^1$ map to greater dimension has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a $C^1$ map. Prove that the image of $f$ is a set of measure zero.

I know the following theorem: Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and let $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ map. If a subset $E\subseteq A$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $g(E)$ also has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to apply the theorem here, so I want to construct a $C^1$ map $F:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, where $A$ is an open set containing $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$ so that $F(x, 0) = f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then, since the set $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the result will follow from the theorem.

I'm thinking that the map $F$ could be constructed on an open set $A=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon>0$. How can I construct it?

Comment: Just put $F(x,y)=f(x)$.

Comment: @Etienne Indeed, so the derivative in the first $n-1$ directions of $F$ is the same as the derivative of the corresponding direction of $f$. So it is continuous since $f$ is $C^1$. The derivative in the $n$th direction of $F$ is $0$, which is clearly continuous. So $F$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Yes. Or you could say that $F$ is $\mathcal C^1$ because $F=f\circ\pi$, where $\pi$ is the projection on $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, which is $\mathcal C^1$.